# SQL "missing in or out parameter at index"

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

i have this code for create query and execute sql-procedure but i catch missing-exception

```
public String generateQuery(Integer idAccount, Long[] phoneList, Date date){
    StringBuilder query=new StringBuilder();
    query.append("declare arr_pn owa_util.vc_arr;\n");
    query.append("begin\n");
    int idx = 1;
    for (Long p : phoneList)
    { query.append("arr_pn(" + idx + "):='" + String.valueOf(p) + "';\n"); idx++; }
    query.append("call LOC_MAINCLIENT.set_client_relations(");
    query.append("id_account_ => " + idAccount);
    query.append(", phone_number_list_ => arr_pn");
    query.append(", dt_ => " + date);
    query.append("); end;");

    return String.valueOf(query);
}
```

after that i get this query

```
declare arr_pn owa_util.vc_arr;
begin
arr_pn(1):='12345';
arr_pn(2):='678970';
arr_pn(3):='5675675';
call LOC_MAINCLIENT.set_client_relations(id_account_ => 123, phone_number_list_ => arr_pn, dt_ => Sun Mar 24 21:54:00 NOVT 2013); end;
```

what i did wrong?

Comment: How is the procedure defined - particularly it's signature, unless the exception is being called from within it?

Comment: The date string being passed to dt_ beenclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @vishad i`m stupid. please, show me how

Comment: Any particular reason why JDBC API calls or methods are not used?

Comment: legacy-code. i must use this =(

Comment: @mechanikos As mentioned by AlexPoole, without procedure code or signature, it is  quite difficult.

Comment: iknow,  i have not procedure code. i have not idea about what doing this procedure -_-

Comment: @mechanikos Do you have procedure's expected IN OUT parameters and their data types?

Comment: @mechanikos And try executing your generated PLSQL code in backend and as pointed out by vishad, data parameter doesn't look quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the date string isn't quoted, so it's in valid anyway, but the colons will be interpreted by the parser as bind variable markers; specifically it'll be looking for bind variables :54 and :00.

The quick answer is to put the date string into quotes. But that date format is unlikely to match what your database (session) is expecting, so you'd need to format the date into a string it can use and provide the format as well to avoid ambiguity.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    query.append(", dt_ => to_date('" + sdf.format(date)
        + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')");
```

You also don't need the `call`, so get rid of that. That would produce a string like this (with added line breaks and indentation to make it a little easier to see):

```
declare
  arr_pn owa_util.vc_arr;
begin
  arr_pn(1):='12345';
  arr_pn(2):='678970';
  arr_pn(3):='5675675';
  LOC_MAINCLIENT.set_client_relations(id_account_ => 123,
    phone_number_list_ => arr_pn,
    dt_ => to_date('2013-03-24 21:54:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
```

Assuming your package procedure is declared as:

```
procedure set_client_relations(id_account_ number,
    phone_number_list_ owa_util.vc_arr, dt_ date);
```

... this this should run. Whether it does what you actually want is a different matter, of course.

You may also need to do something with the time zone if the database doesn't match your locale.

The proper way to do it is to use a prepared statement, provide all the values as bind variables, and pass the correct data types - passing the date as a date rather than as a string representation. That's a little more complicated for an array but certainly do-able. You've said this is legacy code and you have to use this, but you should still investigate switching to bind variables.